# Writing repeated values in array quickly

Tags: c++, arrays, file, memory

I have a quick question on writing to a file quickly using C++. I am working with a grayscale color image, thus I store a single 8-bit value (ranging from 0-255) in an array for each x,y position of the image.

However, after I've read in these, values, I need to write them out as an RGB format, thus storing 3, 8 bit values for each x,y position.  The intuitive thing to do is then just write each value 3 times in a row before moving to the next value.

Here is an example code of what I am doing:

```
for(int f = 0; f < totalFrames; f++){
    for(int i = 0; i < imageSize; i++){
        int index = i +(f*320*240);
        myFile << pixelBuffer[index];
        myFile << pixelBuffer[index];
        myFile << pixelBuffer[index];
    }
}
```

If the values in the array were all stored contiguously, I could simply use:

```
myFile.write((const char*)pixelBuffer, totalFrames * imageSize);
```

But that is not the case, so I wonder if there is a way I can offset where I am writing each value to, so I can just make three write calls per frame, rather than imageSize*3 writes.

Comment: I don't think there is any practical way to make this quicker. Assuming pixelBuffer is a regular array with fast lookup.

Comment: I am worried this might just be the classic space versus time trade off.  Because I am capturing the original grayscale image from a camera, I need those writes to be fast and take the least space possible.  Otherwise, I would just store the duplicated values, read them into pixelBuffer and then do one single write in my above code.

Comment: Not all writes are equal. A single write of 3 would be about the same speed as three writes of 1. The file is buffered by default to absorb small writes.

Comment: "If the values ... were all stored contiguously" ... what kind of pixelbuffer do you use? At least you should be able to write each frame in one go with `myFile.write()`, shouldn't you?

Comment: The pipeline is: Read data from camera-> Store in array -> myFile.write()

So you are correct I can do this.

The second part of the pipeline(the part the above question is about) is:

myFile.read(pixelBuffer,size) -> Write into a new format that is 3 times as large as the original buffer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either transfer the data into a for-writing array, or use memory-mapped IO (if you're working with Windows `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFileEx`, Linux/Mac uses `mmap`).

```
using pixel_t = /* what type is your data? */;
pixel_t* writeBuffer = new pixel_t[imageSize];
pixel_t* writePtr = writeBuffer;

for(size_t f = 0; f < totalFrames; f++){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < imageSize; i++){
        const size_t index = i + (f * 320 * 240);
        const pixel_t data = pixelBuffer[index];
        *writePtr++ = data;
        *writePtr++ = data;
        *writePtr++ = data;
    }
    myFile.write((const char*)writeBuffer, imageSize); 
}

delete[] writeBuffer;
```

Using the memory mapped IO, you'd do very much the same thing, you just wouldn't need the "write" statement.

Comment: I think this will be the best solution, and should lead to some performance increase.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this.

Write your pixels to a memory buffer `std::stringstream` and then dump that to a file:

```
std::stringstream ss;

for(int f = 0; f < totalFrames; f++){
    for(int i = 0; i < imageSize; i++){
        int index = i +(f*320*240);
        ss << pixelBuffer[index];
        ss << pixelBuffer[index];
        ss << pixelBuffer[index];
    }
}

std::ofstream myFile("myfile.pix");

myfile << ss.rdbuf();
```

**EDIT:**

You can also set the size of the internal buffer to avoid reallocation:

```
char buffer[size_of_image];
ss.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, size_of_image);
```

Comment: I don't see what this achieves other than extra complexity and overhead.

Comment: Is `size_of_image` big enough for any null terminator or extra data required by stringstream? (I don't know. I've never used it this way) You should also open it in binary mode.

Comment: @Neil This method will only be effective if the overhead of each write to disk file is greater than the overhead of each write to a memory buffer + a block-write of the entire buffer to file. Best to test & see if the improvement (if any) is worth it.

Comment: fstream is already buffered, you are just adding another buffer.